# tex4ht: conflict between hyperref and cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, tex4ht

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  \label{test}
  This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

Look at \Cref{test}.

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `make4ht`, I get errors

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   14   Argument of \@fourthoffive has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   14   Paragraph ended before \@fourthoffive was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   14   Argument of \@fifthoffive has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   14   Paragraph ended before \@fifthoffive was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   14   Paragraph ended before \hyper@readexternallink was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   14   LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

A workaround is to remove `\usepackage{hyperref}` which does not seem to affect the `html` output. However, I wonder why they are conflict under tex4ht and a better solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by fix for another issue - [clashes between Hyperref and Biblatex](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?534). If you don't use Biblatex, you can reintroduce the original code using this version of `cleveref-hooks.4ht`:

```
% cleveref-hooks.4ht (2021-06-30-14:33), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2020-2021 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2021-06-30-14:33}

\let\HyOrg@addtoreset\@addtoreset
% fixes for \refstepcounter
\let\orig:refstepcounter\refstepcounter
\let\orig:@thm\@thm
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
\let\refstepcounter\orig:refstepcounter
\let\@thm\orig:@thm
}

\RequirePackage{nameref}
```

This is the result:

[image]

At this moment, I don't know what is the correct solution that will work across all packages. So this is just a temporary fix.

Comment: Is there any reason to import the `hyperref` package for `tex4ht`? Seemingly, even when it is not imported, the links are compiled into hyperlinks by default.

Comment: @Yai0Phah in general, I think you should import hyperref with TeX4ht only if you use commands that it provides (like `\href`). Otherwise, it isn't really useful.

Comment: You are correct. `\hyperref` is defined in this package.